# Why does the following batch code crash?

Tags: batch-file

Why does this code crash?
(Batch or MS DOS)
I am new to programming so sorry if this is a stupid question.

```
    echo set var=string>>batch.bat
    call batch.bat
    If %var%==string goto LABEL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `batch.bat` (because you are appending a line to it)?
You have no `:LABEL` in your code so GOTO fails.

Try this:

```
@echo off
echo set var=string>batch.bat
call batch.bat
If %var%==string goto :LABEL
:LABEL
echo this is the end
pause
```